# generic method to create an instance from an object

Tags: java

Is this a safe way to create an instance (assuming T has a accessible default constructor) ?

```
<T>
public T defaultObj(T obj) throws Exception {
    return (T) obj.getClass().newInstance();
}
```

Because of the type erasure, the above codes will generate an unchecked warning.  Is it possible to get rid of this warning other than @SuppressWarnings?

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Yes, I know if I could pass a `class<T> type` which would be much better.  But let's just assume it is out of question for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what `@SuppressWarnings` is supposed to do: this code is safe (because calling `getClass()` on an object of type `T` actually yields `Class<? extends T>`), but compiler cannot understand it (return value of `getClass()` is declared as `Class<?>` due to limitations of generics) and generates warning.

It's absolutely legal to use `@SuppressWarnings` in this case, and you shouldn't try to avoid using it.

Comment: Thank!! This is the reassurance I was hoping to hear.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could change the signature a little to `<T> T defaultObj(Class<T> obj)` and then `newInstance()` will return the appropriate object.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  But let's assume the method signature can't be changed.  Is it safe to use the above codes?

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with axtavt.

Comment: The method signature should be burnt. It doesn't make any sense to do this sort of thing (like most actual uses of reflection).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get rid of this warning other than @SuppressWarnings?

You could constrain `T` to extend some interface that provides a factory method.

```
interface Newable<T>
{
    T getNewInstance();
}

<T extends Newable<T>> T defaultObj(T obj)
{
    return obj.getNewInstance();
}
```

example implementation:

```
class Foo implements Newable<Foo>
{
    @Override
    public Foo getNewInstance() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```